# multiprocessing.manager issue sys.args

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am running the following python line of code within a small windows service application which is multiprocessed.

```
multiprocessing.Manager()
```

The issue is there appears to be no attribute argv within the module sys set when running a windows service. As a result of this I get the following error occur within the python multiprocessing forking library. I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this issue.

Stacktrace of issue (when running multiprocessing.Manager within windows service):

```
 File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 524, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 252, in __init__
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 339, in get_command_line
    if process.current_process()._identity==() and is_forking(sys.argv):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv
```

**Update**

One possible solution to my problem is that I manually set the `sys.argv` value if it is not set at runtime but this seems very unpythonic. But might be the only solution. What do stackoverflow-ers think?

```
if not hastattr(sys, 'argv'):
    sys.argv = []
```

But, this then leads me to a new issue with the multiprocessing.manager where by an unexpected EOFError occurs within the code.

```
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
  EOFError
```

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows system right now, but you if you explicitly set `sys.argv = []`?

Comment: @ldx.a.ldy.c ah yes, I was going to suggest this as a possible solution just wanted to know if this is the only way around this problem. Seems a bit unpythonic that I should have to do this. It also then leads to the error as described within my update to the post.

Comment: Somehow I experience an issue mentioned in **Update** while unittesting in a standalone way. Everything is working as expected with a normal run and when unittesting in PyDev. Did you ever solve your issue in **Update**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting `sys.argv = []` didn't work, if there is a script name you might be able to use do `sys.argv = ['scriptname']` or just `sys.argv = ['']`. The latter is what you get if you run python, import `sys` and then look at `sys.argv`, e.g.,

```
~$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['']
```

Comment: Thank for the comment @sigmavirus24, even when I do what you stated I still run into the second exception as listed within my question. I am not sure if this is a possible python bug

Comment: Was a guess. I've never seen this problem, and I've used multiprocessing frequently. You might do well to ask in #python on freenode. Lots of them are far more knowledgeable than I.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function after Python initialization:

```
PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
```

The interpreter can't get access to argc/argv in other way rather then passing them explicitly from main().